# Bash: Sort files from 'find' by contents

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, find, piping

I have the line:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*key*'  -not -name '*~'
```

I want to extract the contents (which should be text) of all the files returned and pipe that into `sort` to be sorted alphabetically. I've tried piping the output of the above line directly into `sort` but this results in the file names being sorted rather than their contents. Do I need to turn the output of `find` into an array and then have it processed by `sort`?

[edit] The output I want is the sorted contents.

Comment: Pipe it through `xargs cat` then through `sort`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For completeness sake here are a few more ways of doing that:

1. `find -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*key*'  -not -name '*~' -exec cat {} \; | sort`
2. `find -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*key*'  -not -name '*~' | xargs cat | sort`
3. `cat $(find -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*key*'  -not -name '*~') | sort`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to save the sorted output into a file, try:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*key*'  -not -name '*~' | cat | sort > sorted.txt
```

otherwise just get rid of `> sorted.txt` and the sorted output will be printed to the terminal window.